# how to output decoded base64 encoded emails with python's smptd DebuggingServer

Tags: python, base64

I found this awesome one liner to create smtp servers on the fly with python:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Trouble is, my application sends the mail contents base64 encoded, so the output really looks like garbage:

```
---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------
b'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="===============7226846835346479139=="'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'Subject: redacted subject'
b'From: ACME Online 2'
b'To: john.doe@acme.com'
b'Cc: '
b'X-Peer: 10.255.13.37'
b''
b'--===============7226846835346479139=='
b'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'
b''
b'PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMCBUcmFuc2l0aW9uYWwv'
b'L0VOIj4KPGh0bWw+CjxoZWFkPgogICAgPG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iY29udGVudC10eXBlIiBj'
b'b250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7Y2hhcnNldD1pc28tODg1OS0xIj4KICAgIDx0aXRsZT5XZWVrbHkg'
```

and so on.

if I atob this, I get:

```
atob('PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMCBUcmFuc2l0aW9uYWwv')
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional/"
```

**How can I get clean base64 output decoded logs ?**
Ps: I don't want to process logs afterwards, I want a clean output directly. It's running inside a linux docker container.

Comment: You'll have to write your own extension of the [`smtpd.DebuggingServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html#smtpd.DebuggingServer) to use the [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#module-email.message) package to parse your emails, or you'll have to write a different content-aware structure to do base64 decode of the segments that are encoded.

Comment: I find it very strange that `DebuggingServer` doesn't do this automatically by default. It's such an obvious requirement for anyone using it.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @zwer answer, I got to implement a server myself:

```
import asyncore
import email
from smtpd import DebuggingServer

class ActualDebuggingServer(DebuggingServer):
    def _print_message_content(self, peer, data):
        msg = email.message_from_string(data)
        for (header,value) in msg.items():
            print(header, ': ', value)
        for part in msg.walk():
            print('---------- a part: ----------')
            maybe_decoded_payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            if (maybe_decoded_payload is not None):
                print(bytes.decode(maybe_decoded_payload, encoding="utf-8"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ActualDebuggingServer(
        ('0.0.0.0', 1025),
        ('0.0.0.0', 1025)
    )
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

it's really rough, it assumes parts are encoded in UTF-8. Also, i'm not sure what the second argument is for. Use with caution.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I ended up with the same result. I have a `Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"` and it all came out base64 encoded, still.